# Listing SimpleXml Object

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to list an XML file with php SimpleXml :

```
<Record>
      <TestData>
         <Status>Passed</Status>
         <Date Year="2018" Month="1" Day="25" Hour="11" Min="41" Sec="24"/>
      </TestData>
      <ResultData>
         <ResultItem ElementID="42">
            <Status>Passed</Status>
            <ResultItem ElementID="43">
               <Status>Passed</Status>
            </ResultItem>
         </ResultItem>
         <ResultItem ElementID="70">
            <Status>Passed</Status>
            <ResultItem ElementID="72" Version="1">
               <Status>Passed</Status>
            </ResultItem>
            <ResultItem ElementID="100" Version="1">
               <Status>Passed</Status>
            </ResultItem>
         </ResultItem>
      </ResultData>
</Record>
```

This my php code :

```
   $xml = simplexml_load_file ('20000.xml');
foreach ($xml->Record->ResultData as $element) { 
  foreach ($element as $key => $val) {
    echo $val['ElementID'].' '.$key.'</br>';
    foreach ($xml->Record->ResultData->ResultItem as $element1) { 
        foreach ($element1 as $key1 => $val1) {     
            echo '- '.$val1['ElementID'].' '.$key1.'</br>';  
        }            
      }          
  }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
42 ResultItem
- Status
- 43 ResultItem
- Status
- 72 ResultItem
- 100 ResultItem
70 ResultItem
- Status
- 43 ResultItem
- Status
- 72 ResultItem
- 100 ResultItem
```

This is I expect to have:

```
42 ResultItem
- Status
- 43 ResultItem
70 ResultItem
- Status
- 72 ResultItem
- 100 ResultItem
```

Where is the bug ?

How can I differentiate the two "Record->ResultData->ResultItem" in the foreach loop as they have both an "ElementID" attribute wih two different values ?

Comment: Using `$xml->Record->ResultData->ResultItem` in your inner loop starts from the very top again, you need to do similar to your middle loop which starts with the previous loop value (`$element`).

Comment: It would help not just us, but _you_ if you used more meaningful variable names. What do you expect `$element1` to contain? What does `$key1` mean?  Start trying to name things, and you may find you spot your own bugs more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to provided xml structure you can do something like:

```
foreach ($xml->Record->ResultData as $element) { 
  foreach ($element as $key => $val) {
    echo $val['ElementID'].' '.$key.PHP_EOL;
    // iterate over children of current element `$val`
    foreach ($val as $key1 => $element1) { 
      if ($key1 === 'Status') {
        echo '- '.$key1.PHP_EOL;  
      } elseif ($key1 === 'ResultItem') {
        echo '- '.$element1['ElementID'].' '.$key1.PHP_EOL;  
      }            
    }          
  }
}
```